# How can I deal with these "attempt to divide by zero" errors?

Tags: c#-4.0, divide-by-zero

When I am initializing a variable to zero, like `int i=0`, it throws an exception:

> Attempt to divide by zero

How is this possible? The exception is thrown in other cases, also, like getting zero indexed value from a collection: `collection[0]`, and  `if(a%b==0)` etc,.

Please suggest how I can deal with this.

Comment: Dividing by zero (either with standard division or modulus) will through a `DivideByZeroException`.  If you don't want to get that exception check that your divisor isn't zero before dividing.

Answer (score 3):

[DivideByZeroException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an *integral* (such as `int` or `long`) or `decimal` value by zero.

This exception will also be thrown in the case of `a % b` if `b` evaluates to 0.

Either

1. *Guard* the expression such that 0 is never used in the division/modulo, or;
2. Catch the exception (ick)

Comment: +1 for providing both options, guarding is the best solution. If this is happening regularly in your code it might be better to use a function `Divide(int a, int b)` to perform the guarding so you don't repeat yourself and dont forget to guard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch your `Exception` and handle it properly.

```
try
{
   // your code that throws exception
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
   // Perform an appropriate action
   // for example display a custom message
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

For more information see: [**Exceptions and Exception Handling**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)